# Executing a bash script from anywhere on Windows

Tags: bash, shell, windows-scripting

I am on Windows.
I have a script file named **basics.sh** and here is what it contains:

```
cd opt-out-exam/abduvosid_malikov/IT
mkdir made_by_my_script
cd made_by_my_script
echo "Hello World" > hello.txt
```

so basically, **basics.sh** script file is responsible to:

- go to folder **opt-out-exam/abduvosid_malikov/IT**
- make a directory **made_by_my_script**
- create **hello.txt** file with content **Hello World**

Right now. to execute this basics.sh script, I am going to IT folder and writing this command in the terminal:

`./basics.sh`

In order to execute this **basics.sh** script, is it compulsory for me to go to IT folder
OR
is it possible to execute this script file even if I am staying in another folder (lets say currently working directory is opt-out-exam)

Answer (score 1):

The first line is a *change directory* command followed by a *relative* path, not *absolute*. In such cases, it is important where you run the script. (An absolute path would start with the filesystem root, i. e. `/`.)

If you run this script from a *directory* (I wouldn't call it a *folder* in this context) where the relative path `opt-out-exam/abduvosid_malikov/IT` does not exist, it won't `cd` into it. But it will make a new directory without any problem, it will also create the file and write a line into it.

So only the first line will fail if it's run somewhere else.

UPD: As Gordon Davisson pointed out, this means that you want to check whether the directory change actually took place or not.

Comment: This is why you should always check for errors when you use `cd` in a script, and generally exit if it fails (see [shellcheck SC2164](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164)).